# Azure Pipelines - Visual Studio Test does not publish results from TestContext.WriteLine

Tags: azure-devops, mstest, azure-pipelines, vstest, testcontext

We are using Azure DevOps to run a build that runs tests using Visual Studio Test.

Everything is working fine, `Console.WriteLine` lines are being written to `Standard Console Output.log`, however `TestContext.WriteLine` are not appearing in the Detailed report.

The same lines are indeed appearing in the `Output` link on `Test Explorer` in Visual Studio.

---

### Environment Information

**Build Solution:** Visual Studio 2017`

**VSTest:** Latest

**Test Framework:** MSTest.TestFramework 1.3.2

**Test Adapter:** MSTest.TestAdapter 1.3.2

---

Just to reiterate, `TestContext` is being instantiated correctly, and we are able to check the Output on local machine (`Visual Studio 2015 Update 3`), however the Ouput will not be published to Azure Pipelines build

Thank you,
Regards

Comment: I am also having same problem. In my local VS 2017 test cases are passing but when I checkin my code, run my build in Azure DevOps they are failing. I added TestContext.Writeline(..) I want to know where I can see those messages in Azure DevOps...

Comment: Did you find solution...

Comment: Hi @Ziggler, use `Console.WriteLine` or `Debug.WriteLine`, I still have not found a solution for this problem. Regards

Comment: I used TestContext.WriteLine.. In Azure DevOps, I got my build -> run test cases stage. There you will see Publish Test Case Results to link. I go there and download .trx file and open in NotePad and there I see my logs... That's enough for me.